# Python Enum inheritance fail to initialize base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I was plaing with python Enums and I wanted to DRY my code a little bit by moving the `from_string` method to parent class

```
from enum import Enum

class Base(Enum):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    @staticmethod
    def from_string(string: str):
        try:
            return Base[string]
        except KeyError as e:
            raise ValueError(e)

class DeSwitch(Base):
    aus= 'aus'
    zu = 'zu'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class EnSwitch(Base):
    on  = 'on'
    off = 'off'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

def main():
    print(EnSwitch.from_string('off'))
    print(DeSwitch.from_string('aus'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

however after doing this i receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    class EnSwitch(Base):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 252, in __new__
    enum_member.__init__(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

can someone help me understand what's wrong with my example?

Comment: What does your `from_string` method do that, for example, `EnSwitch("off")` and `DeSwitch("aus")` doesn't do already?

Comment: it's repacking error from `KeyError` which is used in dict to `ValueError` which better represents the logic in my case. The reason why I want the `ValueError` is because it's a command line arg that is being parsed by `from_string` method.

Comment: `DeSwitch("INVALID")` raises a `ValueError` already. But note, it expects a *value* not a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Base[string]` will call the `__new__` dunder method of an enum.

`__new__` will then call the initializer of the enum class with the string as an argument (`enum_member.__init__(*args)`).

So in order to make your code work you should add another argument to your initializer

```
def __init__(self, value):
    super().__init__()
```

Also `from_string` tries to create an instance of Base while you should create an instance of one of the subclasses. You can do this by making it a class method.

```
@classmethod
def from_string(cls, string: str):
    try:
        return cls[string]
    except KeyError as e:
        raise ValueError(e)
```

As long as you do not actually do anthing with the initializers you can just as well remove them.

Comment: Thank you, however in both cases ( adding `value` to  `__init__` and removing `__init__` the result is an error: `File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 387, in __getitem__    return cls._member_map_[name] KeyError: 'off'`

Comment: You should also make from_string a classmethod and call `cls[string]` instead. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.